# documentation in "Ubuntu Help" how to avoid translation

Tags: language-support, documentation

I am a gnu/linux user. My computer has a Spanish keyboard and my LANG env var is set to Spanish:

```
$ echo $LANG
es_ES.utf8
```

Whenever I visit the Ubuntu help pages I get the articles tranlated to Spanish. Is not a matter of the browser, I guess the system detects my language and searchs for translated pages automatically. Is there a way to skip that and to get the original Ubuntu help in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's indeed a browser matter. In Firefox you find the applicable setting in *Preferences -> Content-> Languages*. If you prefer that multilingual web pages are displayed in English, make sure that English is at the top of that list.